# Web reference soap wrong wsdl conversion for type xs:time

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, soap, web-reference

I have imported in visual studio a web reference for a SOAP web service.

Inside the WSDL there is one field `XYZ` defined as `xs:time`.

After importing web reference, I see .NET creates in the file *Reference.vb* the field `XYZ` as type `Date`.

When I initialize the web service I need to pass in the field `XYZ` just the time value, for example `00:00:00`.

Because .NET converted into type `Date`, it adds automatically other values for the date and the final value is `00:00:00.0000000+01:00`.

This value generates an error at the web service receiver.

How can I put just `00:00:00` inside this field OR how can I avoid .NET converting the WSDL field `xs:time` into `Date` and convert it to `Time` as is should be?

Thank you very much!

Comment: There's no `Time` type in .NET. You could try to use [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx), but I don't sure, that it helps.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Then forget about the Time type. How can i pass the value "00:00:00" if .net converted the wsdl type to Date ?